# Fwrite random behavior

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to do a script which reads a file and edit it and I'm doing  it with fopen.

My problem is, when fwrite it's supposed to input the word TEST it also delete some stuff and input some numbers no reason.

This is my code:

```
if (($gestor = fopen("files/prueba.pim", "c+")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, "<br>")) !== FALSE) {
        $numero = count($datos);
        for ($c=0; $c < $numero; $c++) {
            if ("G81"==substr($datos[$c], 0, 3)){
                fwrite($gestor, "COMIENZO DE CICLO".PHP_EOL);
            }else {
           if (";"!=substr($datos[$c], 0, 1))  echo utf8_encode($datos[$c]."\n");
            if ("X"==substr($datos[$c], 0, 1) or "Y"==substr($datos[$c], 0, 1))
                fwrite($gestor, "TEST".PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    }
    fclose($gestor);
}
```

The echo is just for testing purposes.

I couldn't manage to paste correctly the input and output dunno why so I paste it in pastebin sorry.

- Input-> http://pastebin.com/ZdRVNGiA
- Output-> http://pastebin.com/VgVpBuD3

As you can see in the output the 2 lines after `G81 I-1. F500.` just disappear, also random numbers and blankspaces appear in some of the lines starting by Y.

Comment: In your code you only write `COMIENZO DE CICLO` and `TEST`, but in provided output I see more data. Maybe you are writing somewhere else to file too? Also, if you wish to append to file, use `a` flag instead of `c` (`c` will overwrite content from begin of file)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Justinas , but as you see using `c+` is not ovewritting the file. Also can you tell me what more data do you see? I don't know what you're talking about. Sorry  if this sounds too rude, it seems to me, but I don't know other way to say this in english ^^

Comment: You should try to create a smaller test case - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some tips and explanations of why this helps both you and us.

Comment: You mix reading from and writing to the same file. Of course you get a mess. Open a new file for writing. Read the data from the first file (`fgetcsv()`), process it then put the results into the second file (`fwrite()`). Close both files then remove the input file (or rename it, to keep it as a backup) and rename the second file with the name of the first file.

Comment: This the input now `G81 I-1. F500.  
X-79.803  
Y64.947  
X-81.468 Y67.451  
X-86.995 Y64.947  
X-97.3 Y68.781
X-107.603 Y64.947
X-109.268 Y67.451
X-114.433 Y66.373
X-119.304 Y66.445
Y78.111` and this the otuput `G81 I-1. F500.
COMIENZO DE CICLO
X-81.468 Y67.451
TEST
95 Y64.947
X-97.3 Y68.781
TEST
603 Y64.947
X-109.268 Y67.451
TEST
433 Y66.373
X-119.304 Y66.445
TEST
1` as you see still write random numbers, gonna try what @axiac says.

Comment: @axiac forever <3 to you, and thanks to everyone who tried to help solved this problem now gonna see if I can end it

Comment: They are not random numbers. The `fwrite()` calls overwrite pieces of your input file. What it seems like random numbers to you are, in fact, fragments of the original file. Put them side by side and count the characters you write and you'll see.

Comment: A wrote an answer that explains the bits and pieces from my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it doesn't work as you think it should work

What you think are random numbers are, in fact, pieces of the input file. Because you read from a file then write into it, you overwrite fragments of lines from the input file.

For example, the lines `16-19` from the input file read:

```
G81 I-1. F500.
X-79.803
Y64.947
X-81.468 Y67.451
```

The code reads line `17` using (`fgetcsv()`) then it writes `COMIENZO DE CICLO` followed by a new line at the current file pointer position (which is at the start of line `18`). The lines `17` and `18` contain 15 characters and two newlines. It seems you are running the code on Windows; it uses two characters to represent a new line and that makes a total of 19 characters for the two lines.

It happens that `COMIENZO DE CICLO` has 17 characters; the new line you write after it adds two more characters and that makes also a total of 19 characters. This way, the lines `17` and `18` from the input are replaced exactly by a single line that contains the text `COMIENZO DE CICLO`.

This is how lines `16-18` appear in the output file:

```
G81 I-1. F500.
COMIENZO DE CICLO
X-81.468 Y67.451
```

The next call to `fgetcsv()` reads from the current file-pointer position and this is at the start of line `18` (it used to be line `19` before the `fwrite()`; the line numbers are for humans, the code uses the the offset from the beginning of the file to keep their internal booking.) The content of the original line `18` (`Y64.947`) was ignored by the code then overwritten. It was lost without being processed.

The next lines in the file (lines `18-20` after the first `fwrite()`, `19-21` in the original file):

```
X-81.468 Y67.451
X-86.995 Y64.947
X-97.3 Y68.781
```

The code reads line `18` (`X-81.468 Y67.451`) and decides it has to `fwrite('PRUEBA'.PHP_EOL)`. The current file pointer is at the beginning of line `19` (line `X-86.995 Y64.947`). `fwrite('PRUEBA'.PHP_EOL)` overwrites the first `6+2` characters from that line:

```
X-86.995 Y64.947               <--- original
^^^^^^^^
PRUEBA..                       <--- replacement
```

(I used dots instead of the new line characters) changing it to look like:

```
PRUEBA
 Y64.947
```

There is a white space character before `Y64.947`. It was in the input file and it was not overwritten.

The part `X-86.995` was lost forever without being read and the next call to `fgetcsv()` reads the line  `Y64.947` and probably doesn't do what you want.

This goes on and on until the end of file is reached.

#### How to make it right

The following piece of code shows how to correctly process the file. You need to complete it with the code that puts into the output file the pieces read from the input file that do not need to be replaced. The place where this code is to be inserted is marked with a big comment that also suggest what to write there.

```
$gestor = fopen("files/prueba.pim", 'r');
$output = fopen('files/output.txt', 'w');

// Test if fopen() succeeded for both files
if ($gestor == FALSE || $output == FALSE) {
    // Handle the error somehow (return from function or exit the program
    // or display an error, it depends on your application).        
    exit(1);
}


// Read, process, write
while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, "<br>")) !== FALSE) {
    $processed = FALSE;
    $numero = count($datos);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $numero; $c ++) {
        if ("G81" == substr($datos[$c], 0, 3)) {
            fwrite($output, "COMIENZO DE CICLO".PHP_EOL);
            $processed = TRUE;
        } else {

//         if (";" != substr($datos[$c], 0, 1)) {
//             echo utf8_encode($datos[$c]."\n");
//         }

           if ("X" == substr($datos[$c], 0, 1) or "Y" == substr($datos[$c], 0, 1)) {
               fwrite($gestor, "TEST".PHP_EOL);
            $processed = TRUE;
           }
        }
    }

    // Here you probably need to fwrite($output) the rows that didn't match
    // the conditions above (nothing was output for them)
    //
    // This is how I would write it:
    //     if (! $processed) {
    //         fwrite($gestor, implode('<br>', $datos).PHP_EOL);
    //     }                             ^
    //       +---------------------------+
    // Put here the same string you used as the third argument to fgetcsv()
}

// Close both files then rename them
fclose($gestor);
fclose($output);

// Remove the previous backup, if any
if (file_exists('files/prueba.pim.backup')) {
    unlink('files/prueba.pim.backup');
}
// Backup the input file
rename('files/prueba.pim', 'files/prueba.pim.backup');
// Replace the input file with the output file
rename('output.txt', 'files/prueba.pim.backup');
```